# htaccess: assets redirection returns 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect the assets requests to the correct real path, my website root folder contains the following files:

- .htaccess
- main-site/
- new-site/

the root .htaccess is as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new\.mywebsite\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new-site/index.php [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main-site/frontend/web/index.php [L]
    
    # Non-www to www redirect
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

then inside main-site dir, I have the following htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/main-site/(assets|css|images|js)/
    RewriteRule ^/main-site/assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/main-site/css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/main-site/js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L] 
    RewriteRule ^/main-site/images/(.*)$ main-site/frontend/web/images/$1 [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|images|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

but any request to the assets like this will always return 404:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/main-site/plugins/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js
```

Comment: Is `/main-site/plugins/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js` the actual file-path to the asset? Or are you expecting it to be rewritten? You mention "assets redirection" in the title, but none of your rules actually match that request? There are a number of errors/inconsistencies in the directives you've posted, but you've not explained what you are actually trying to do here?

Comment: `/main-site/plugins` is not included in your `RewriteRule`, therefore that file should be directly on disk under your content directory.  Is it?